# Identify connector type

Tags: connector, identification

Can someone help me identify this connector? I need to source a male to plug into it.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That connector is originally an AMP type, now TE Connectivity, known as a MATE-N-LOCK. They come in a variety of layouts regarding number of pins and placement of the round and D-shaped cavities used for keying.

Here is a link to the data sheet: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/418/NG_CD_350766_Y5-626930.pdf

[image]

Comment: Can I ask for more info? I ordered this part but was only supplied the housing. Do I need to order the connector pins separately? Presume there is some sort of pin that goes inside the connector?